# Summoned Items Pop Out of Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to summon an item inside a glass block (it's not because it's transparent or even glass, I tried with concrete too, an it still happened), but it just jumps out, which defeats the purpose of it being in the block. Does anyone know what I can do to stop this from happening?

Comment: Perhaps if you just want the item to sit there permanently you can give it custom tags and then teleport it to that spot in a repeating command block?

Comment: Not sure if this would work inside a block, but it's what I use when I want floating items on 1.12.2: /summon Item ~0 ~0.5 ~3 {Age:-32768,PickupDelay:32767,NoGravity:1b,Health:32767,Invulnerable:1,Item:{Count:1,id:"minecraft:dirt"}}

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with normal items, not even `NoAI` helps. But you can do something very similar: You can summon an invisible armour stand with an item on its head. Example:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1,Marker:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"stone",Count:1}]}
```

Comment: Sounds great, but I want the item to be able to be picked up, as well as reset.

Comment: Then /give it to the player once he gets close and kill the armour stand.